# Generalized Laguerre function $ L^{\alpha}_n(x)$ fo $\alpha$ not necessarily a positive integer

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, orthogonal-polynomials

Is what we can define the generalized Laguerre function $ L^{\alpha}_n(x)$ for $\alpha=-1$ for all $n\geq 0$ and $x>0$?

Comment: I do not unterstand. What do mean? And what is $j?$

Comment: The quantity is well defined $L^{-1}_n(x)$, where $n\geq 0$ and $x>0$ ? my problem is the valued $-1$ for $\alpha$

Comment: I still do not understand. $L_n^{-1}(x)$ is a polynomial with 
$$\frac{\partial}{ \partial x} L_n^{-1}(x) = -L_{n-1}(x)$$
according to Wolfram Alpha  `LaguerreL(n,-1, x)`

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding ODE for $L^{-1}_n(x)$ is $xy''-xy'+ny=0$ .

According to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%22-xy'%2Bny%3D0 , it seem that $L^{-1}_n(x)\propto xM(1-n,2,x)$ .